# Installing Ubuntu 20.4.3 LTS alongside Linux Mint 20.2

Tags: dual-boot

I would like to install Ubuntu 20.04 and use the Plymouth bootscreen with all options while booting. This does not work on my Packard Bell EasyNote LV11 HC since I have Linux Mint 20.2 (Cinnamon).

---

Original (German)

**Title:**

Wie kann ich Ubuntu 20.4.3 LTS auf meinem Notebook - neben Linux Mint 20.2 installieren?

**Question:**

Ich möchte beim booten den Plymouth - Bootscreen mit allen Optionen nutzen - das funktioniert auf meinem Packard Bell EasyNote LV11 HC seit ich Linux Mint 20.2 (Cinamon) habe nicht mehr.

Comment: My apologies if the German is not quite accurate. I'm still learning the language ... 

Comment: This question is about **installing Ubuntu** alongside Mint. It is on topic.

Comment: You can follow the official tutorial https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop Once you have installed Ubuntu, you can ask another question about configuring Plymouth.

Comment: Hi , inzwischen habe ich Mint 20.2 mit dem Upgrade auf 20.3 Una versehen - der Plymouth-Bootscreen startet auch hier nicht. Als ich noch Ubuntu 19.4 hatte und daneben LM Cinnamon funktionierte das einwandfrei . Ich vermisse beim booten die Kernel - und Recouvery Optionen. Ausserdem gibt es oft Probleme bei Neustarts des Systems.Sowie beim Shotdown.